# Rails error in migration ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to remove column and index in `activities` table. To do so I've got below migration:

```
class RemoveUnnecessaryJourneyActivitiesRelations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    remove_index :activities, :cms_journey_id
    remove_column :activities, :cms_journey_id, :bigint
  end
end
```

When I run `rake db:migrate` it removes this column and index as well but when I want to reset my DB by `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed` or `bin/rails db:setup` I'm getting an error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'cms_journey_id' for Activity.
```

Comment: Where do you have this error? Can you give some code?

Comment: Like I wrote - when I run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed` or `bin/rails db:setup`

Comment: Yes but from where is coming your exception? Don't your have a stacktrace? Try `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed or bin/rails db:setup --trace`

Comment: My supposition is that you still have a reference to `cms_journey_id` in your code. Running your migrations trigger this code, which cause the error since you don't have the column anymore. What I'm trying to do with the stacktrace is check that my supposition is correct. But maybe you can just search for `cms_journey_id` in your code and remove any potential remaining reference?

Comment: Nope, I searched and I don't have any reference in my code to this column

Comment: I won't be able to help without a stacktrace (we all know what's the meaning of this error, but without any reference to your code I don't have the competence to help you resolve the issue, sorry)

Comment: Damn, I've some references in `seed.rb` and that was the issue. Thanks for help!

Comment: Ok, perfect :) My pleasure

Answer (score 0):

How was the attribute added in the first place? If it was via a migration it looks like that file had been deleted.

You have two options - if you want to get the above migration working, you'll need to insert one before it (with an earlier timestamp) that creates the attribute, and then run this migration to remove it.

Of course, the easier option is to just delete the above migration. Because there is no migration that creates the attribute, you can delete the above migration, run `rake db:migrate`, have a look at your `db.schema.rb` file, and you'll see no column called `cms_journey_id` on the `activities` table.

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote and no - I've got this `cms_journey_id` in my schema. That's why I want to remove this column originally.

Comment: Turns out I had some references in `seed.rb` and that was the issue.